# How to match empty column height with re-scalable column in the next

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

In a table row, one column is having red border but no contents in, next column is having long text area which is re-scalable, I had used percentage for the red border column so if the long text area is scaled even the red border line of the first column should match the same height

This works as expected in chrome but not in Firefox and it not renders height in percentage, I cannot use pixels or em as the value is not fixed which gets changed when the user scale the height of the long text area in the second column

Please refer the screen shot, thanks

Comment: where is the screenshot? show some code please....

Comment: Thanks for the reply here is the screen shot
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-XFka9dmvkVaTdaN080TEtHcHM/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-XFka9dmvkVZGdEMUNvdmVXU2c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have to specify a fix height.
When you work with percentage, most of the time the table adapts to body content...